# What free VPN server to use that would work with iOS?

Tags: vpn

iOS supports 3 VPN solutions: L2TP, PPTP and IPSec and currently I'm using PPTP connecting to a Ubuntu server.

Also, there are several problems: PPTP configuration has to be tunned on both ends in order to make it work and also I heard that PPTP can be broken in just 4 hours.

Is any other better solution for setting up Apple compatible VPNs that would not require buying some commercial software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not set up L2TP if you don't want to harden PPTP further? There are a plethora of guides on the internet on setting up VPN using AWS free service micro tier instances and Ubuntu.

Here is one article from the AWS support forum with a discussion and links to how-to articles for setting up L2TP over IPSec on Ubuntu:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=286936

Answer (score 2):

For years I've gone through this cycle of trying to set up a home VPN (running on OS X or Ubuntu) that'll support client connections from both my Mac and iPhone/iPad, and hours later I give up in defeat. Six months pass and I think, "it can't really be THAT difficult" ... and the cycle repeats.

Anyway, a couple weeks ago I finally got *everything* working. Some genius posted exactly what's necessary to get VPN set up for iOS and it also worked with my Mac:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1645473&highlight=openswan+iphone

Comment: Whilst your answer may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the article in an answer below, and provide the link for reference

Comment: Sadly, openswan can't be directly downloaded with apt-get anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Use RouterOS, almost free, easy and stable.
They have lots of [VPN server](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Category%3aVPN) options.

Your could use it in combination with [Routerboard](http://routerboard.com/RB750GL)

Answer (score -1):

There are two Free VPN services that you can choose to go with, Express VPN and Hotspot Shield. They would work absolutely fine on yur iOS and in my opinion they are the best choice. You can choose any among them.